# Can a Foursquare checkin function be added onto a website?

Tags: foursquare

Can a Foursquare checkin function be added onto a website?

Answer (score 2):

Although you can provide check-in capability on a web site, please use caution and realize that it may be difficult to comply with the appropriate Foursquare API requirements.

(Poster amelvin is correct that the API you need is at http://developer.foursquare.com/)

However keep in mind:

- You need to find an accurate representation of the user's lat/long in order to create a check-in with the API
- You should not spoof the location
- You may be dependent on using modern browser's location capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Use the [foursquare api](http://developer.foursquare.com/) to add foursquare checkin to your site.